# jQuery incrementing ids of cloned descendents by 1

Tags: jquery, clone, identity

I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nmovimentos").change(function () {
        var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value
        this.defaultValue = this.value;
        if (direction) {
            var $div = $('div[id^="novomov"]:last');
            var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
            var $clone = $div.clone().prop('id', 'novomov'+ num)
            $clone.insertAfter('[id^="novomov"]:last');
            $('[id^="darktheme"]:last').text('+ '+num+'º Novo Movimento');
            // get all the inputs inside the clone
            $clone.find('*').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).prop('name');
                var id = $(this).prop('id');
                $(this).prop('name', name+num);
                $(this).prop('id', id+num);
            });
        }
        else {
            $('[id^="novomov"]:last').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, it clones the div element with `id="novomov1"`and increments the number at the end everytime. So, for the 1st clone, the id is `id=novomov2`. It was suppossed to do the same thing for all the names and ids of the clone's descendents, but it is only working with the names. For the descendent's ids, the numbers at the end are not being added, they are being placed at the end of the number. For example, an `id="mov1"` becomes `id="mov12"`, `id="mov123"` and so on... Why is that occuring if the code is the same for the names and ids?

```
<div id="novomov1">
    <table>
        <tr>    
            <td id="darktheme1"> +New Moviment</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tabela1">
        <tr>
            <td id="mov1">
                Type:<br>
                <input name="tipomov1" id="l1" type="radio" value="1" >Line</input>
                <input name="tipomov1" id="c1" type="radio" value="2" >Circle</input>
                <input name="tipomov1" id="r1" type="radio" value="3" >Rotate</input>
                <input name="tipomov1" id="m1" type="radio" value="4" >Move</input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would advise against using incremental `id` attributes. It's a pain to maintain, and just causes issues. Instead, use DOM traversal to find the required element you need from the element that raised the event within the repeated block.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
    $(this).prop('id', id+num)
```

your id is a string so instead of adding the values numerically, it concatinates the value as a string.  That's why mov1 becomes mov12.  To fix this you need to mimic what is done above in:

```
    var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
```

The parseInt turns it into an integer so it is numerical addition instead of string concatination.  Such is the fundamental issue with "loosely typed" languages like javascript.

Comment: I tried it.. no luck :( I think that in `var id = $(this).prop('id');`  I have to get only the literal part of the id in order for it to work (get only `mov` form `mov1` for example), so the number can concatenate only with a word.. do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you very much!!

Comment: If the regular expression isn't working then you can parse out the id.  If you know it is 3 characters plus a number then you can parse it out using substring(0,3) for the 'mov' part and substring(3) to get the number.  Then use parseInt on the number part, iterate it, and put them back together.